# Как сделать так, чтобы в XmlDom работал XPath?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Если в экземпляре `XmlDocument` присутствуют пространства имён, отличные от пространства имён по умолчанию, то все запросы `XPath` возвращают пустое множество. Писал в запрос префиксы, полные идентификаторы пространств имён - безрезультатно. Приходится во вложенных циклах перебирать узлы и проверять их имена и атрибуты.

Кто-нибудь знает, как сделать так, чтобы работало нормально?

Более конкретно задача выглядит так: получить из файла проекта на C# имя сборки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так точно работает:

```
    XmlDocument projectXmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    projectXmldoc.Load("Project2012.csproj");

    XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(projectXmldoc.NameTable);
    nsManager.AddNamespace("default", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003");

    XmlNodeList nodeList = projectXmldoc.SelectNodes("//default:Reference/@Include", nsManager);
    foreach (XmlNode RefInclude in nodeList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ссылка на сборку: {0}", RefInclude.InnerText);
    }
```